# Unit testing - Find code coverage for conditions in mysql queries

Tags: mysql, unit-testing, code-coverage

I have a function which executes mysql queries having multiple CASE and WHERE conditions. **My question is, any code coverage tool (like EclEmma) shows that the code coverage is complete even when all scenarios in the SQL query have not been covered.**

Forexample:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN a_col=1 THEN 'Value is 1' CASE WHEN a_col<10 THEN 'other' ELSE 'none' END WHERE b_col>100
```

In this case the code coverage tool (like EclEmma) says that coverage is complete even when the query is executed once. Query has to execute at leaset 3 times with different vakues of a_col to complete the coverage. **How to ensure that coverage.**

Comment: EclEmma is for Java coverage, it doesn't know about SQL.

Comment: @Manu So, what do we do to find coverage of applications using SQL queries?

Comment: anyone got an answer for this? any good advise here would help.

Comment: The only code coverage tools I know of for SQL (stored procedures) are https://github.com/kputnam/piggly (for PostgreSQL) and https://github.com/GoEddie/SQLCover (for Microsoft SQL Server). I don't know of any that works with MySQL/MariaDB.